# loop.index returns NaN

Tags: twig

I'm using TwigJS in a webpack project. A very simple twig template returns `NaN` for loop.index, however when I use loop.index0 it appears to be working as usual. 
Also, loop.first returns always `false`. I can't figure it out why.

```
{% set items = [1, 2, 3] %}

{% for item in items %}
    {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```

output:

```
NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Should work as is. Try a clean install?

Comment: clean install works indeed. Thanks